# What is the difference between .() and .{} in Reason?

Tags: reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to figure out why the example for using `Js.Promise` uses

```
Js.Promise.(
    ...
)
```

Whereas the example for `Json.Decode` uses

```
Json.Decode.{
    ...
}
```

From what I understand, `.()` opens up `Js.Promise` so that I can just call any function within `Js.Promise` without having to prefix `Js.Promise` as the module.

But what does `.{}` do?

Comment: From what I gather, `.{ ... }` is really a shorthand for `.({ ... })`, but I'll need someone who has more experience to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both put some module declarations in scope, but `.{}` creates a record while `.()` wraps an expression.

For records:

```
let point = json =>
  Json.Decode.{
    x: json |> field("x", float),
    y: json |> field("y", float)
  };
```

is equivalent to:

```
let point = json =>
  {
    x: json |> Json.Decode.field("x", Json.Decode.float),
    y: json |> Json.Decode.field("y", Json.Decode.float)
  };
```

Similarly, for expressions:

```
let _ =
  Js.Promise.(then_(value => resolve(Js.log(value)), okPromise));
```

is equivalent to:

```
let _ =
  Js.Promise.then_(value => Js.Promise.resolve(Js.log(value)), okPromise));
```